# What's the difference between a programmatically request and a 'real' one?

Tags: network-programming, request, google-chrome-devtools

I'll try to be more precise.

What's the difference between a request programatically created using all the request headers that appear in the Network tab from the Google Chrome Dev Tools and a 'real' one?

Or, in other words: could the server notice when I'm using the programatically created and when I'm using the 'real' one if I send a programatically generated request using all the request headers that Chrome says I'm sending when doing the 'real' request?

Comment: Do you think the "real" request is *not* "programmatically created"?

Comment: Maybe not in the sense that Chrome has access to some OS services that a backend language has not. So, that's a: there is no difference?